# WordPress comment_post action not working

Tags: php, wordpress

In my plugin I want to accomplish an action after a comment is inserted into the database.

for that I use [comment_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post) action. Here is my code

> *Codex*: ***comment_post***  is an action triggered immediately after a comment is
>   inserted into the database.

```
/*
* Plugin Fonctionalities Class
*/

class PluginFonctionalities {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('comment_post', array('do_action_comment'));
    }

    public function do_action_comment( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {
        if( 1 === $comment_approved ){
            $outputFile =  plugins_url('includes/output.txt', __FILE__);
            $filehandle = fopen($outputFile, 'a') or die("File creation error.");
            fwrite($fileHandle, "Example of message");
            fclose($fileHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing is happen when i submit the comment form. Any ideas !?

Comment: Have you instantiated the class? `new PluginFonctionalities()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your object as the first array element, and the method as the second (i.e. [array callable syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing)):

```
add_action( 'comment_post', array( $this, 'do_action_comment' ), 10, 2 );
```

This is covered in ["using with a class"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_with_a_Class) in the Codex.